# Is there a word for a surface that DOES have friction?

Tags: friction, terminology, soft-question

When talking about models in physics, I want a way to differentiate between surfaces that have negligible and considerable friction. We have "frictionless" for surfaces where friction is negligible, but is there a word like "friction-full" or something synonymous with that for surfaces with considerable friction in the same physical setting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v2) as off-topic because it seems to be more about the English language than physics.

Comment: Agreed. Vote the same way. There is no physics in the question, and what is scary is that it elicited over 200 views, so far.

Comment: So, it's already answered, and it clearly has to do with physics and proven by textbooks, but for some reason you're in denial that it has to do with the conventions that physicists use? That seems anti-science.

Comment: Rock climbers talk about how "grippy" the soles of their shoes are.

Comment: I asked my dog this question and he said *ruff*!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, indeed. If a surface has friction that can affect an object then the surface is simply and almost universally called **rough**. You’ll often see this stated in many mechanics or physics books in solving problems.